# Why my old tablet doesn't support some css lines in hybrid app?

Tags: android, html, css, hybrid-mobile-app

I try to make a hybrid app (using PhoneGap) but my main problem is that so far i looks different on every platform. I the browser on PC and on the Android 5.0+ looks as I want to but on older versions of android appear some problems. I've tested it on a 2 different tablets. Both with Android 4.2.2.(Samsung and Lenovo). Both of them don't recognize font unit vw (vh neither). One on them doesn't recognize commend "border-radius" or at least irregularly: [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skPvV.jpg). Whereas the second one has some troubles with animations e.g. like this one:

```
.totheleft{
animation-name: nalewotrzy;
animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@keyframes totheleft{
to {transform: translate(-100%, 0%);}
}
```

And now I don't know if maybe the old versions of Android don't support CSS3 or I implemented my css file incorrectly into html code:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css"/>
</head>
```

I'm quite new in programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until Android 5.0 Lollipop the WebView in each device is part of the Operating System image. Unfortunately this means that unless the OS is updated that HTML5 features/bugs are frozen in time.

With Android 5.0 the WebView is now based on a Google Play updated component called Android System WebView.

See: https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview

Alternatively you could use the CrossWalk Project: https://crosswalk-project.org/ as your WebView for a more consistent experience on old Android versions (4.1 and higher) but at the cost of making your app bigger due to adding in its own WebView.

See: https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/about/faq.html#Distributing-Crosswalk-Project-applications and [71mb added to app size for crosswalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30391023/71mb-added-to-app-size-for-crosswalk)

Comment: And I have one more question. I added crosswalk plugin (version 1.3.0) to my app and on one tablet everything works perfectly (is only much slower and bigger) but the other one doesn't recognize some UTF-8 letters. In my case polish letters. Do you have any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Sorry don't know. There are a few questions on SO about crosswalk and language/characters that you can look at and see if any are appropriate. I would also check the crosswalk project buglist to see if its a known issue. When all else fails, post a new question and state what you've researched/tried.