# Chrome Web View not active on tablet

Tags: android, css, google-chrome, android-webview

I have a phone, Galaxy S4 and a tablet, Galaxy Tab both running Android 4.4.2.

I'm running a custom app that loads a Chrome Web View:

```
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    mWebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);

    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();

    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(this, "Android");

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        cookieManager.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(mWebView,true);
    } else {
        cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
    }
```

This works absolutely fine on the phone, however on the tablet, certain css rules are not being applied:

```
transform: rotate(180deg);
```

I do not have the -webkit prefix, but since it works on the phone, it leads me to believe that it is using the default webview and not the Chrome one

http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d

Also, I can attach the chrome desktop browser inspect tool while debugging to the phone, but not to the table.

Is there any reason why a Chrome Web View would not load on this device?

Comment: Could you see what the User-Agent is perhaps?

Comment: Chrome WebView only came into existence with Android 5.0 Lollipop - See my related answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41876179/why-my-old-tablet-doesnt-support-some-css-lines-in-hybrid-app