# Android : Embedded crosswalk has a 46 MB increase in apk size

Tags: android, crosswalk

I previously read this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30391023/71mb-added-to-app-size-for-crosswalk) post of having an additional 71MB.

Now I am getting an additional 46 MB instead of the promised 20 MB from crosswalk according to [this](https://crosswalk-project.org/blog/crosswalk-lite-10.html), I'm declaring my crosswalk dependency like the snippet below.

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://download.01.org/crosswalk/releases/crosswalk/android/maven2'
    }
}

dependencies{
    compile 'org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:20.50.533.12'
}
```

Crosswalk-lite lacks some of the functionalities that I need and I don't want to implement the shared mode of crosswalk.

Is there anyway of getting the 20 MB increase in APK size? Or is this normal with embedded mode of crosswalk in android??

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to split your application into multiple apk's for different architectures. You will get few different apk's with smaller size.

More info here: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html