# Add/download crosswalk in run time when need

Tags: ionic-framework, crosswalk

my app's size is about 5 MB.
I use of crosswalk in my app for run on android 4.4 and less.
but when add crosswalk to my app for run in android 4.2 increased size to 30 MB.
is there solution for add/download crosswalk after install app on device and if android version less of 4.4 ?
I want to install app in device if android version less 4.4 then download crosswalk then add to app.
I can to use crosswalk Download Mode in ionic ?

Comment: You can try adding crosswalk lite, it will consume less size, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30391023/71mb-added-to-app-size-for-crosswalk

Comment: Possible duplicate of [71mb added to app size for crosswalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30391023/71mb-added-to-app-size-for-crosswalk)