# Reduce APK file size in Intel XDK with cordova and Ionic

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, apk, cordova-plugins, intel-xdk

I have developed an application in Intel XDK with cordova and Ionic, the file size of the apk is 38MB. Even a small application with "hello world" is around 20MB.  How can I reduce the file size of apk built from Intel XDK?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The output of intel XDK (.apk) is too large ! (android)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22246214/the-output-of-intel-xdk-apk-is-too-large-android)

Answer (score 0):

You are probably building your app with Crosswalk, which includes an alternate webview for Android that allows your HTML5 app to work well on Android 4.x devices, as well as Android 5+ devices. This will increase the size of your APK by approximately 20MB.

If you plan to restrict your app to installation on Android 5+ devices, you do not need to use Crosswalk. However, if you plan to support Android 4.x devices, as well, I highly recommend you continue to build with Crosswalk (and suffer the increased size of your APK).

The "Optimize with Crosswalk" checkbox in the Build Settings section of the Projects tab controls the inclusion or exclusion of the Crosswalk webview. More information regarding using Crosswalk in your Android app can be found in the Intel XDK documentation, start here > https://software.intel.com/en-us/xdk/docs/using-the-crosswalk-for-android-build-option

Comment: I have already selected that "Optimize with Crosswalk" checkbox also.

Comment: Since you have selected the "Optimize with Crosswalk" checkbox it means that the extra size you see in your APK package is due to the inclusion of the Crosswalk webview. I've edited my response for clarification, it sounds like my response is the answer you were seeking.